# neo4j Traverser restricting size

Tags: java, neo4j

Is there a way to augment this

```
public static Traverser getSubReferences(
        final Node reference )
{
    TraversalDescription td = Traversal.description()
            .breadthFirst()
            .relationships( RelTypes.SUBREFERENCE, Direction.OUTGOING )
            .evaluator( Evaluators.excludeStartPosition() );
    return td.traverse( reference );
}
```

So that it returns only nodes that are length 1 away from the reference node?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this includes any paths with a length greater or equal 1. If you want to limit to a depth of 1, use `Evaluators.toDepth(1)`.